# Confusing arc length formula in calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

So I am having problems with this section in my math book on the first example. In the first example it uses general constants and this makes it very confusing, at least for me. I understand up until it integrates then I don't understand what exactly is going on. Where has the number one gone, and why is there now a X outside of the square root?

distance between two points $(x_1 ,y_1)(x_2 ,y_2)$
$$ f(x) = mx +b   $$
$$f'(x) = m =(x_2 - x_1)/(y_2 - y_1)$$
[image]

$$ \int_{x1}^{x2}\sqrt{(1 +f^{'}(x)^2) } dx $$

Comment: They have brought the two fractions under the root to a common denominator and then added them.

Comment: thank you, I just figured it out I think, they integrate with respect to x so 1 is now x and the slope is now slope*x so you pull out the x then get a common denominator and combine the fractions. Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: I was confused too until I saw there were some kind of equations in relatively small print just above the big fuzzy photograph. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/139123 for advice on formatting the equations so they can be recognized easily like the ones in the photo; ideally you would format _all_ the equations that way and not use a photo at all, although if you have never used MathJax or LaTeX before it might seem difficult to format those integrals correctly.

Comment: Thanks David, I didn't know that. I check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has happened between step two and three is that under the root, they split up the square between the numerator and denominator of that fraction, and find common denominators to combine it with the one. The $x$ comes from integrating the function. Since the square root and what's under it are constant and do not rely at all on $x$, integrating just gives that constant times $x$. You then evaluate it from $x_1$ to $x_2$.